# How to load multiple scripts in Mongo sequentially

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to load multiple scripts using `db.load('path/to/script/with/other/order/dependent/scripts')`.  That script loads other scripts.

I thought maybe 'bulk' execution might be the answer, however there is no load method, and the 'bulk' execution only works with one collection at a time.